# Run executable in Qt failed while successful in windows cmd

Tags: windows, shell, qt

I want to eject removable USB disk in Qt application, and was using a tool from Microsoft called **Sync**([download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sync)) , the usage is **sync.exe -e [E:]**

So I was running this tool from Qt with code below:

```
QString ejectToolPath = QString("%1/sync.exe").arg(qApp->applicationDirPath());
QStringList params;
params << "-e" << driveLetter;
QProcess::startDetached(ejectToolPath, params);
```

after running this code, the removable Usb disk was not ejected, and if I use the tray icon to eject the disk, it warns the disk is in use.

But if I use the windows explorer tray icon or run the sync.exe in cmd or powershell, it was able to eject that device.Am I missing something or there is difference between run the exe in shell and in Qt.

This problem has tormented me for days, hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance!

**[2022-03-03 update]**

After testing, I narrowed down the scope of the problem.
My application scenario is like this, First click the QPushButton to popup the removable device list, then select the device to eject, on click of the menu item, call the real eject function.
By the way, the device list widget is set the Qt::Popup attribute.

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Popup);
```

I found if I directly call eject device function, it performs OK, but if fail on click the popup menu item with the same code. what was the difference?

SUCEESS:

```
void HMStatusBarWidget::onPluginButtonClick() {
ejectDevice("D:"); // **success**
/*QHash<QString, QString> deviceList;
if (deviceListWidget_ == nullptr) {
    deviceListWidget_ = new PopupListWidget(this);
    connect(deviceListWidget_, &PopupListWidget::textItemClicked, [=]() {
        ejectDevice("D:"); // **fail**
        });
}*/
....
```

FAILURE:

```
void HMStatusBarWidget::onPluginButtonClick() {
//ejectDevice("D:"); // **success**
QHash<QString, QString> deviceList;
if (deviceListWidget_ == nullptr) {
    deviceListWidget_ = new PopupListWidget(this);
    connect(deviceListWidget_, &PopupListWidget::textItemClicked, [=]() {
        ejectDevice("D:"); // **fail**
        });
}
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my problem. When I was enumerating removable usb disks, I forget to close the device handle. This cause the device in use, It has nothing to do with Qt.
Thanks for your help! @mugiseyebrows

```
STORAGE_HOTPLUG_INFO HMStatusBarWidget::getDeviceType(char driveLetter)
```

{
STORAGE_HOTPLUG_INFO Info = { 0 };

```
HANDLE hDevice = getDeviceHandle(driveLetter);
if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    CloseHandle(hDevice);
    return Info;
}

DWORD bytesReturned = 0;
DeviceIoControl(hDevice, IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_HOTPLUG_INFO, 0, 0, &Info, sizeof(Info), &bytesReturned, NULL);
CloseHandle(hDevice);

return Info;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's the case but better way to build path to executable is

`QString ejectToolPath = QDir(qApp->applicationDirPath()).filePath("sync.exe")`

Qt builds application in `debug/` or `release/` folder if shadowbuild is disabled and in `build-xxxx` folder if enabled, are you 100% sure `sync.exe` is in application folder? It wont hurt to check again.

`qDebug() << QFile(ejectToolPath).exists()`

If it's there `startDetached` can only fail to start if one of libraries that `sync.exe` depends on is not in %PATH%.

Does sync expect path or drive letter? `E:` may be considered as ivalid path, the correct version is `E:\` - with mandatory trailing slash.

Comment: I checked "sync.exe" is in application path, and the path exists.
"sync.exe" expect E or E: or E:\ are all ok, I have checked under cmd.

Comment: another point you mentioned that sync.exe may depends something is not in %PATH%, how do I know what it depends? 
I have also test that if I start powershell from Qt and then run sync.exe on it, alse failed.

Comment: You can use [dependencywalker](http://dependencywalker.com/) for dependancies, to get %PATH% in qt use `QStringList paths = QString::fromLocal8Bit(qgetenv("PATH")).split(";");`

Comment: As you suggest, I used dependencywalker, and found sync.exe only depend on several system dll under c:\windows\system32:

c:\windows\system32\SETUPAPI.DLL
c:\windows\system32\SHLWAPI.DLL
c:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
c:\windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
c:\windows\system32\USER32.DLL
c:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.DLL
c:\windows\system32\SHELL32.DLL
and c:\windows\system32 is in %PATH%

Comment: Sync requires administrative privileges to run, do you run your application with administrative privileges?

Comment: Sync no need administrative privileges to run, although my application run as administrative privileges. I narrowed down the scope of the problem, and updated the content above.

Comment: It is writen here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sync#introduction "Unfortunately, Sync requires administrative privileges to run"

Comment: Even though he wrote that, it seems no administrative privileges needed. Anyway, my application is configured to requiredAdministrator, so this should not a problem.